# JSON PHP Decode

Tags: php, json

i have an extern JSON File and no problems to get Airline, Price, etc..
But how can i get [ACE] ?

```
[success] => 1
[data] => Array
    (
        [ACE] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 477
                        [airline] => AB
                        [flight_number] => 2434
                        [departure_at] => 2014-08-09T12:30:00Z
                        [return_at] => 2014-08-24T08:35:00Z
                        [expires_at] => 2014-04-03T22:46:17Z
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Please drop your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$foo = $json['data']['ACE'];` should do it.

Unless you want to get the key from the `$data` array, in which case:

```
foreach ($json['data'] as $k=>$v) {
    $foo = $k; // this is 'ACE'.
    break;
}
```

Edited as per comment.

Comment: $foo = $json['data']['ACE']

Comment: But i dont know the Value ['ACE']. Its always different.

Answer (score 0):

['ACE'] is an array?

Your getting the data from it starting with the first -  [0]

Then the ['price'] of the first one?